# Paste.ee api upload

Tags: python, api

I am trying to upload to paste.ee through the api, however, I keep getting the error: `{"errors":[{"field":"sections","message":"The sections must be an array.","code":-1},{"field":"sections","message":"The sections must be an array.","code":-1},{"field":"sections","message":"The sections must be an array.","code":-1}],"success":false}` This is the code I am using:

```
import requests
payload = {'key': 'apikey', 'sections':[{'name':'Section1', 'syntax':'autodetect','contents':'name'}]}
post_response = requests.post(url='https://api.paste.ee/v1/pastes', data=payload)
print post_response.text
```

What am I doing wrong? [Here's](https://pastee.github.io/docs/#submit-a-new-paste) an entry on their wiki.

Comment: full, verbatim error message is required.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The full error message is: {"errors":[{"field":"sections","message":"The sections must be an array.","code":-1},{"field":"sections","message":"The sections must be an array.","code":-1},{"field":"sections","message":"The sections must be an array.","code":-1}],"success":false}

Comment: please edit your question to include that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have done so. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: hm, it's interesting you're getting the error three times: Shouldn't you be serializing `payload` as json first, or does `requests.post` do that automatically? I'd have something like `data=json.dumps(payload)`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Doing that returned the message "{"errors":[{"code":1,"message":"No application key supplied."}],"success":false}". The first one authenticated, this one didn't.

Comment: No, the first one didn't authenticate, either, it was rejected before auth could even happen. Read my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're not using `requests` correctly: See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests:

> For example, the GitHub API v3 accepts JSON-Encoded POST/PATCH data:
>
> ```
> >>> import json
>
> >>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
> >>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>
> >>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
> ```
>
> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly
>   using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be
>   encoded automatically:
>
> ```
> >>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
> >>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>
> >>> r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
> ```

You're, however, try to send a Python dictionary directly. You should probably be doing

```
import requests
payload = {'key': 'apikey', 'sections':[{'name':'Section1', 'syntax':'autodetect','contents':'name'}]}
post_response = requests.post(url='https://api.paste.ee/v1/pastes', json=payload)
print post_response.text
```

And debug the issues you get then.

The example from the docs you link to is:

```
curl "https://api.paste.ee/v1/pastes"
  -H "X-Auth-Token: meowmeowmeow"
```

Therefore, this is what a paste.ee auth header seems to look like

```
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'token'}
```

and thus, your whole program should probably look like

```
import requests
payload = {'sections':[{'name':'Section1', 'syntax':'autodetect','contents':'name'}]}
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'token'}
post_response = requests.post(url='https://api.paste.ee/v1/pastes', json=payload, headers=headers)
print post_response.text
```

Comment: Have you tried using this? I'm getting an error still "{"errors":[{"field":"sections.0.syntax","message":"The selected sections.0.syntax is invalid.","code":-1}],"success":false}"

Comment: nice, so your original issue is solved and you can now proceed debugging the next one :)

Comment: by the way, the `syntax` field is optional, and since you're only using the default value, what about omitting it?

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I think that paste.ee (whatever it does) seems to be buggy as hell.